# $f$ analytic in $D(0,2)$ and satisfies $f'(0)+af'(0)=0$. Show that

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

I need to show that if $f$ is analytic in the disk $D(0,2)$ and satisfies $f'(0)+af'(0)=0$, then:

$$\int_{|z|=1}\frac{(1+a\xi)f(\xi)}{\xi^2}d\xi = 0$$

I truly have no idea what to do with this. What does it mean $f'(0)+af'(0)=0$? I know I have to integrate around the circunference but... what?

I know that you guys prefer that I show some work but this $f'(0)+af'(0)=0$ thing really does not ring a bell. Could somebody help me?

Comment: Is there a typo in your condition and it should be $f'(0) + af(0)=0$? Then your claim would follow directly from the Cauchy integral formula.

Comment: Note that because $f$ is an alaytic function inside the unit circle, the only pole of your integrand is at $\zeta=0$. the corresponding residue reads $\partial_{\zeta} (\zeta^2 \frac{1+a \zeta f(\zeta)}{\zeta^2})$. Using the constraint suggested in the other comment you can conclude by the residue theorem